# How to prevent element from staying active?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, single-page-application

I have a modal on a single page app that pops up when user makes a certain action. If user presses on one of the buttons(yes/no) the modal closes. If the same modal pops up again, the last pressed button stays active. I use pseudo-class `:active` to change the buttons background when it is pressed.

This happens on some android touch devices.

HTML:

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <p class="modal-title" data-bind="lang: Title"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" data-bind="lang: Body">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="exitFooterButtons">
                    <div class="ExitButton">
                        <div data-event="yes" data-bind="lang: 'Modal.Yes'"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ExitButton" data-event="no" data-bind="lang: 'Modal.No'"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
modal .modal-content .modal-footer .ExitButton {
    line-height: 54px;
    width: 50%;
    display: table-cell;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 54px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    color: #c6c6c6;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: url(../Images/headerRowBackground.png) repeat-x; 
}
```

And :active

```
modal .modal-content .modal-footer .ExitButton:active {
    background: url(../Images/reverseHeaderRowBackground.png) repeat-x;
}
```

If I press NO for the first time, and come back to the modal second time, then NO is still active. If I then press YES and come back again for the third time, both of them are active.

Comment: Do you use a jquery plugin for the modal or is it custom-coded?

Comment: It's bootstrap modal with our own design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by replacing div's with `buttons`

```
        <div class="exitFooterButtons">
            <div class="ExitButton">
                <button data-event="yes" data-bind="lang: Languages.Yes"></button>
                <button data-event="no" data-bind="lang: Languages.No"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

In conclusion, some android(~4.2) devices don't like `:active` pseudo classes when they are assingned to `div's`.